# I fell to start resourcemanger ,datanode and the "http://localhost:8088/cluster" after I start-all.sh of hadoop 3.3.1

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, configuration

The real condition of my terminal shows that: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG6BB.png)

After I look it up in the log, it says

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.Inaccessible0bjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.class java.lang.classloader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError a ccessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7cc0cdad
```

My java version is the jdk16,and I am not sure whether is the problem of the java version

### Here are my configuration XML files:

**1. My core-site.xml configuration:** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwqK1.png)

**2. My hdfs-site.xml configuration:** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KihY.png)

**3. My yarn-site.xml configuration:** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfH3b.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you are not using Java8 or 11